# PWA: Pre-Cashing of Javascript Module Files not Working

Tags: javascript, caching, module, progressive-web-apps

I have implemented pre-caching of some files in my progressive web app. It is working for all other files except javascript module files. When I go offline, these files are not found in cache, although I can see them in the cache in the browsers' developer tool. The affected files are those that are loaded using import or loaded using

```
<script type="module" src="/js/xxx.js"></script>
```

All the other files are available offline including the javascript files that are not loaded as modules. My fetch event is implemented as follows:

```
// fetch event
self.addEventListener('fetch', evt => {
        evt.respondWith(
            caches.match(evt.request).then(cacheRes => {
                console.log('**Request URL-->' + evt.request.url, cacheRes);
                **//cacheRes always returning 'undefined' for javascript module files 
                //although i can see them in browser cache**
                return cacheRes || fetch(evt.request).then(fetchRes => {
                    //other code .....
                });
            }).catch(() => {
                    //handle error .....
            })
        );
});
```

What could be the problem ?

Comment: For some reason, I have realized that if I use **caches.match(evt.request.url)** instead of **caches.match(evt.request)**, then caches.match can now find the javascript module files. Unfortunately, some other cached resources that could be found using **caches.match(evt.request)** cannot be found now. Can someone explain this ? So, in the interim, I have called **caches.match(evt.request.url)** after the first **caches.match(evt.request)**, that is ... 
                `return cacheRes || caches.match(evt.request.url) .....`